# Possibility vs Feature

Tags: software

Is it ok to use the word Possibility when referring to features of a software application?

As in this example: "In this release, we have added a possibility to display some data..."

Comment: No. Added the ability to display... Or have made it possible to display...

Comment: "Added the possibility to display some data" -- **if** you buy the extra-cost feature and **if** you can navigate through 12 screens of setup every time you use it.  Using "possibility" gives all sorts of wiggle room, if that's the intent.  "Added the *capability* to display some data" would be more meaningful, if the wiggle room is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP: No

Suggest:

*"added the capability/ability **to display"***

*"added the capability/ability **of displaying"***

"Possibility" is **too weak**. "Capability" **shows empowerment**.

Comment: I thought so. But the phrase "make something possible", which is used very often when describing software features, confuses me, e.g. "this feature makes it possible to display some data..." So, I wonder, if you can use "possible", why can't you use "possibility"? E.g. "This feature adds the possibility to... "

Comment: See update. ....

Comment: @PassingBy: The verb "add" wants something more definite than a "possibility". The primary meaning of "possibility" is "the potential for something to exist or occur" whereas "to make possible" means "to provide a means to do or achieve something".

Comment: Marius Hancu, Tim Romano, thank you. I think I now understand both why "add possibility" is incorrect, and the difference between "add possibility" and "make something possible"